# How to solve: Problem with converting pkcs12 file into a pem

Tags: certificates, encoding

I am trying to convert a client certificate from a pkcs12 type to a pem file using openssl, but this error is showed on my terminal. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I haven't edited or manually changed the p12 file. Even when I try to get some info from the .p12 file it shows error.

```
# openssl pkcs12 -in Desktop/cert.p12 -nokeys -out Desktop/cert-file.pem
139728018543680:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
139728018543680:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=PKCS12
```

Comment: Not enough is known about your actual \*.p12 file. But check out https://serverfault.com/questions/677093/openssl-cannot-convert-pkcs12-exported-from-cisco-asa-55xx for a possible solution to your problem  - which is the first hit when searching for [asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag pkcs12](https://www.google.com/search?q=asn1_check_tlen%3Awrong+tag+pkcs12)